# Azure Mobile App with MSAL JWT validation failed IDX10500

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to authenticate a Xamarin.Forms app against my Azure Mobile App backend (which has been set up to use Azure AD authentication) using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL). This is so that the app can access tables API Controllers etc, but I am having issues authenticating fully.

In the app (client side) it kind of seems like I am able to successfully login because I got the Azure AD login screen in Safari web browser but straight after entering my credentials I get redirected to the app and I am presented with the following error from MSAL:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

I did some digging and attached a debugger to my Mobile App backend and that revealed the following:

> Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware Verbose: 0 : Received request:
>   POST https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
>
> Exception thrown:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException'
>   in Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.Modules.dll
>
> Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware Warning: 0 : JWT validation
>   failed: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve
>   SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
>       (
>
> ```
> IsReadOnly = False,
> Count = 1,
> Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
> ) ',
> ```
>
> RawData: eyJ0eXAiOiJ......
>
> token:
>   '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","kid":"-sxMJMLCIDWMTPvZyJ6tx-CDxw0"}.{"aud":"d03a8a86-2d38-4017-a8e6-d1813c7a8b99","iss":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/03afca2b-f47f-4d0b-9a25-d464aff5d399/v2.0","iat":1550228705,"nbf":1550228705,"exp":1550232605,"aio":"ATQAy/8KAAAAJ5N6SdnFdK7rYxWxvwbUKLAjZesFNkwaj2jR7tQg+E10FU5giL0DQM7SWbfwwYNG","name":"GFSSD
>   TEST","oid":"ea10e59f-4466-451c-b7df-e9727ae5b899","preferred_username":"gfssd@mycompany.com","sub":"aPg-fkuZz4lwGIPSGbQ-nOoj7BPwT4_bBsb9UvATAdI","tid":"03afca2b-f47f-4d0b-9a25-d464aff5d399","uti":"tpY2tvyphUib1O2N4wIQAA","ver":"2.0"}
>
> Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware Information: 0 : Sending response: 401.83 Unauthorized

Any ideas why it doesn't seem to authorize properly?

**EDIT:**

[image: Mobile App Authentication Settings]

Comment: Hmm, have you setup the back-end AAD to use the v2 endpoint? Seems like you have a v2 token.

Comment: By "back-end AAD", I assume you are referring to the AAD App Registration? The answer to that would be no, it's just a standard app registration via portal.azure.com, not even the Preview type either, if that helps.

Comment: Actually, just for some extra info, I have 2 app registrations a Native one and a Web app / API one, it is possible that the Native one was set up with App registrations (Preview), as it was someone else in my organization who did it.

Comment: Ah I meant the back-end app :) All apps are essentially v1 and v2 compatible. It depends on what you configure as the authority for the API.

Comment: And also what you configure as the token version through the preview experience in the API app's manifest.

Comment: Ah OK no problem. So going back to your original question, I am not sure how to find that information out? I have set the "Issuer Url" as https://login.microsoftonline.com/03afca2b-f47f-4d0b-9a25-d464aff5d399/v2.0 in the portal for my app service under Authentication / Authorization -> Azure Active Directory -> Advanced, if that's what you mean?

Comment: It's related, the issuer is correct and matches the token. Based on the error it seems like it is loading the wrong set of public keys as it can't find the one that corresponds to the private key that was used to sign the token. I'll have to check if those were different for v1 and v2...

Comment: Could you add the configuration you have under Authentication / Authorization to the question? You can redact the ids of course.

Comment: @juunas I've added a screenshot to it now.

Comment: Hmm, it could be that only supports v1. You could try specifying the issuer without the v2.0, and set the accepted token version to 1 in the API manifest under the preview app registration.

Comment: @juunas OK, I've done both of those things, removed /v2.0 from the Issuer URL in the app service, and set accessTokenAcceptedVersion = 1 in the Web app registration but I am still experiencing the same issue "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Comment: @juunas After doing those two things you suggested, the iss is still the exact same with the /v2.0 at the end of it. Could this be part of the problem? I am rapidly losing hair over this :)